# Using the rails-i18n and devise-i18n gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Target is Rails 5.1
```

I was under the impression that i18n support is baked into Rails, but I've seen the gems rails-i18n and devise-i18n. Do they add value that's not already built into Rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does come with [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) *support* by default, but it doesn't actually translate anything to other languages. That's what the [rails-18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem does. It adds translation files for

> **Available locales are:**
>
> af, ar, az, be, bg, bn, bs, ca, cs, cy, da, de, de-AT, de-CH, de-DE, el, el-CY, en, en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-IE, en-IN, en-NZ, en-US, en-ZA, en-CY,eo, es, es-419, es-AR, es-CL, es-CO, es-CR, es-EC, es-ES, es-MX, es-NI, es-PA, es-PE, es-US, es-VE, et, eu, fa, fi, fr, fr-CA, fr-CH, fr-FR, gl, he, hi, hi-IN, hr, hu, id, is, it, it-CH, ja, ka, km, kn, ko, lb, lo, lt, lv, mk, ml, mn, mr-IN, ms, nb, ne, nl, nn, or, pa, pl, pt, pt-BR, rm, ro, ru, sk, sl, sq, sr, sw, ta, th, tl, tr, tt, ug, ur, uz, vi, wo, zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-TW, zh-YUE
>
> **Complete locales are:**
>
> af, da, de, de-AT, de-CH, de-DE, en-US, es, es-419, es-AR, es-CL, es-CO, es-CR, es-EC, es-ES, es-MX, es-NI, es-PA, es-PE, es-US, es-VE, et, fa, fr, fr-CA, fr-CH, fr-FR, id, ja, ka, ml, nb, nl, nn, pt-BR, sv, sv-SE, tr, zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-TW, zh-YUE, uk

so you can drop in those files and have a decent starting point for rails' baked in strings. (Take a look at any of the [any of the locale files](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) to see what translations you end up getting).

For the [devise-i18n](https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n), per the gem's README:

> Devise supports i18n in controllers, models, and in other areas, but it does not have support for internationalized views. devise-i18n adds this support. Devise also does not include the actual translations. devise-i18n does this too.

Devise is a gem written independently for use with Ruby on Rails, and the author didn't add support for I18n into the views. This gem, then, overrides the views supplied by Devise in order to add in I18n support, as well as supply [translation files](https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n/tree/master/rails/locales) for a ton of different locales (skimming through, looks like roughly the same list as the rails-i18n gem)